# Apple Maps bike turn by turn directions?

Tags: ios, airpods, maps

I'm often biking with my AirPods and have Apple Maps set for biking directions. I was really hoping it would give you audio directions (i.e. turn by turn directions) just like it does when you're driving in your car.

This seems like it should be possible, but I can't figure out how to enable the feature. I'm guessing flipped a switch or a setting somewhere that disabled it and can't figure out how to re-enable it.

The best I *sometimes* get is an beep in one ear and the other, but (A) it seems related to turns, but I have no idea what it actually means (e.g. turn left or right), (B) it only sometimes happens, and (C) it would be a lot more useful to hear the street name to look out for.

While navigating through Apple Maps using bike directions, is there a way to hear the turn by turn directions through the AirPods?

Note: I realize I could probably do this by starting driving directions, but I'd rather avoid that since I'm hoping bike directions will prefer roads with bike lanes and/or other shortcuts that only bikes can take.

Comment: Have you considered using google maps?

Comment: @anonymous: I did not. The main reason I've been using Apple Maps is so I can follow the route on a map view on my Apple Watch as well. Google Maps does not seem to have a map view on the Watch. However, if Google does bike turn by turn, I may consider sacrificing the Watch map for the audio directions.

Comment: Are you able to get turn by turn cycling directions on your phone as it might not be available in your city: https://www.apple.com/ios/feature-availability/#maps-cycling

Comment: I know google maps gives audio directions on every method of transportation (including bicycling). I’m slightly unfamiliar with Apple Watch, can you use it to play audio from iPhone?

Comment: Try using Waze instead?